# How to solve this quadratic nonhomogenius differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation

$r'(t) = \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{a}{1+a^2t^2}\right)^2 r(t)^2}$ where $r(0)=0, r'(0)=1$

I have no clue how to solve it, my usual techniques fail (such as separation of variables, direct integration, and a lot of things that don't apply because it is nonhomogenius and nonlinear). I also tried to find some substitutions to separate the variables without success.

With the rescaling $r\rightarrow r/a,t\rightarrow t/a$ as suggested by JohnBarber and a subsitution $t=\tan(u)$ (where the time domain $[0,\infty)$ maps to $[0,\pi/2)$) this can be simplified to

$r'(u)^2+r(u)^2=\dfrac{1}{\cos(u)^4}, r(0)=0, r'(0)=1$

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

As it was asked in the comments: the background is the following geometrical problem:

A point $A$ moves along a the line $y=1/2$ with position $x(t)=a⋅t$ with constant velocity $a>0$. A second point $B$ starting at the origin $O$ tries to "stick to" the (moving) line $AO$ while using its remaining velocity component of total velocity $|v|=1$ to move away from $A$. The movement of $B$ in polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ is such that $\varphi(t)$ follows trivially from the problem while $r(t)$ satisfies the above equation. More detailed, one derives that $\varphi'(t)=2a/(1+(2at)^2)$ and plugs it into $|v|=1$ which leads to the above equation.

[image: description of geometrical problem]

The geometric view suggests that with inreasing distance $r$ there might be a point in time where $B$ cannot compensate the rotational motion of $A$ anymore which is when the term under the squareroot becomes negative.

Comment: Have you tried a power series solution?

Comment: where does the equation come from? (book, ...) PS: a slight change of analytic form of a ODE may result in solvability in term of elementary functions

Comment: @BlackMild The problem comes from the following geometrical problem: A point $A$ moves along a the line $y=1/2$ with position $x(t)=v\cdot t$ where $v>0$ is fixed. A second point $B$ starting at the origin $O$ tries to "stick to" the (moving) line $AO$ while using its remaining velocity component of total velocity $|v|=1$ to move away from $A$. The movement of $B$ in polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ is such that $\varphi(t)$ follows trivially from the problem while $r(t)$ satisfies the above equation.

Comment: @user619894 Sorry I accidentially wrote $r$ instead of $r^2$, which is now fixed. I assume that You mean a power series approach $r(t)=r_0+r_1t+r_2t^2+...$. No matter if discussing the now corrected version which is alternatively $r'^2+A(t)r^2=1$ or the previous wrong version, which would anyhow still have been quadratic in $r'$, I would have thought that as long as you have a nonlinear form, a power series approach would always result in complicated product terms in the $r_i$, but I might give it a try :)

Comment: @BlackMild For completeness and as I cannot edit my comment, $v=a$ in the terminology

Comment: @BlackMild As mentioned above, I accientially posted the wrong equation, do You think Your PS still apllies? If yes, can You give me another hint?

Comment: @user619894 Inserting a power series approach $r(t)=\sum_{n\geq0} r_n t^n$ into $r'(t)^2+\frac{a}{1+a^2t^2}r(t)^2 = 1$ already in order $t^0$ leads to $ar_0^2=1$ which would contradict the initial condition $r_0=0$. Also in the version before my correction (which you referred to) this problem would occur in the form $ar_0=1$.

Comment: One small change that makes things slightly simpler by getting rid of the $a$: Make a change of variables $r\rightarrow r/a$, $t \rightarrow t/a$. Then we have $r'(t) = \sqrt{1 - {\left(\frac{r}{1+t^2}\right)}^2}$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thanks, I first underestimated this hint, but it brought me to the idea of substitution of $t=tan(u)$ into your simplified form, which (if I made no mistake) leads to $y'(u)^2+y(u)^2=sec(u)^4, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$

Here the "complicatedness" seems to be shifted mainly into the inhomogenity.

Comment: Solving $r'(t) = \sqrt{1 - {\left(\frac{r}{1+t^2}\right)}^2}$ numerically suggests the solution is quite close to simply $r(t) = t$.

Comment: @flonk `y'=x+y` is easily solvable, while `y'=x+y^2` does not have solutions that expressed via elementary functions. In generally, it is not expected ODEs can be solved analytically. So consider numerical solution? (except your problem comes from a book that already confirmed that it can be solved analytically)

Comment: @JohnBarber Yes I also looked at the numerical integration, but seek the analytical solution. Another fact is, considering the aforementioned substitution $t\rightarrow u$,  I just found one special solution by playing which however doesn't fulfill the right initial conditions given by $y(u)=1/cos(u)$. Could this help somehow?

Comment: @BlackMild yeah thanks, I am also quite sceptical, but the matter of my question is to find an analytical solution or a proof that it doesn't exist.

Comment: The book claims there is an analytic solution? Does the book give you the ODE for $r(t)$, or did you derive that from the statement of the problem?

Comment: @JohnBarber There is no book, I just posed the problem to myself ;)

Comment: @flonk 100 years before, the time before Poincare, people had a dream of finding analytic solution of ODEs, and they disappointed. Then Poincare pointed out that "finding analytic solution of ODEs" is not so meaningful; he coined the term "qualitative theory of ODEs" to stress that: properties of solution is more important than analytic expression of solutions. "A proof that solution doesn't exist" is back to the time of proving 5th polynomial can not be solved in generally, that use solvability of some groups. Our modern time is of computers, numerical solutions, and simulation

Comment: @JohnBarber Yes your interpretation of the wording is correct, but it does *not* imply $r'(t)=1$, $r'$ is the radial velocity, i.e. the change of the variable $r$ in time. The motion is "always on the line", yes, but because the line intself moves, at every fixed point in time, a velocity component perpendicular to the radial direction is needed. In more purely formal words, if You consider polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$ and $r'(t)=1$ then you would have $\varphi'(t)=0$ and $B$ would never "rotate", it would just move straight along the $y$-axis, which is obviously not what problem describes.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted my comment, so I deleted it.

Comment: @BlackMild I got the point that there might possibly be no analytical solution and also that the question for existence might be *undecidable*. I am aware of those points and regardless of what "our modern time" might be about I don't fear the disappointment and *enjoy* this despite the danger of wasting time ;)

Comment: @BlackMild What you say is true, and I have no reason to believe this particular problem has an analytic solution, but looking at a numerical solution of an ODE is about as satisfying as watching a robot solve a Rubik's Cube.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from
$$(1+t^{2})^{2}(1-r'(t)^{2})-r(t)^{2}=0$$
postulate a power series with integer powers:

$$r=t+a_{2}t^{2}+a_{3}t^{3}+\cdots \text{(the first term deduced from i.c.)}$$

$$r'=1+2a_{2}t+3a_{3}t^{2}+\cdots$$
Using a CAS for I get:

$$-4ta_{2}+t^{2}\left(-4a_{2}^{2}-6a_{3}-1\right)+t^{3}\left(-12a_{2}a_{3}-10a_{2}-8a_{4}\right)+t^{4}\left(-9a_{2}^{2}-16a_{2}a_{4}-9a_{3}^{2}-14a_{3}-10a_{5}\right)+ 
t^{5}\left(-26a_{2}a_{3}-20a_{2}a_{5}-4a_{2}-24a_{3}a_{4}-18a_{4}-12a_{6}\right)+O\left(t^{6}\right) =0$$
Solving term by term
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}
a_{2} & = & 0\\
-4a_{2}^{2}-6a_{3}-1 & = & 0\\
-12a_{2}a_{3}-10a_{2}-8a_{4} & = & 0\\
-9a_{2}^{2}-16a_{2}a_{4}-9a_{3}^{2}-14a_{3}-10a_{5} & = & 0\\
-26a_{2}a_{3}-20a_{2}a_{5}-4a_{2}-24a_{3}a_{4}-18a_{4}-12a_{6} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

by inspection $a_{2},a_{4},a_{6}=0$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
-6a_{3}-1 & = & 0\\
-9a_{3}^{2}-14a_{3}-10a_{5} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
so $r=t-\frac{1}{6}t^{3}+\frac{5}{24}t^{5}+\cdots$

It seems like $r$ may be odd, but I haven't managed to prove this.

Comment: I have shown that $r$ odd is consistent, so together with uniqueness and the initial condition this means indeed $r$ is odd. I wonder if the asymptotic for large $t$ is also amenable.

Comment: It's straightforward to show that $r(t)\rightarrow t$ for large $t$, which also follows from the geometry of the problem. Also, I think it _must_ be odd. The ODE $r'(t) = \sqrt{1 - {\left(\frac{r}{1+t^2}\right)}^2}$ is invariant under $t\rightarrow -t$ and $r\rightarrow -r$, but is _not_ invariant under $t\rightarrow -t$ and $r\rightarrow r$.

Comment: $r(t)\rightarrow t$, but what next? Probably $c/t$.

Comment: Some playing around in Mathematica suggests that the next term is $-\frac{1}{2}\log(t)$. I _think_ $1/(8t)$ comes after that.

Comment: @JohnBarber Are you sure? if $r\sim t$ then ${\left(\frac{r}{1+t^2}\right)}^2\sim {1\over t^2} $

Comment: @JohnBarber As the ODE is not linear, could You please explain how I can conclude oddness from Your statements on invariance?